# Где в Laravel хранить пути к файлам чтобы потом их извлечь?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть изображения   пути к которым я записал в базу данных, программа нормально работало, но на форумах прочитал  что это не правильная практика, а информации где хранить пути к файлам, кроме базы данных не нашел.

1. Где хранить пути к изображениям.
2. Скажите пожалуйста почему хранить пути к изображениям в базе данных
   не правильно.

Comment: Абсолютно все пути - не правильно. Изображения, которые касаются стилей - в css, А те, которые в посте (продукте т.е.) в базе. Не гоже доставать пост/продукт из базы, а потом еще гдето искать путь к его файлам

Comment: Хранить __пути к файлам в БД__ - распространенная практика. Хранить __сам контент файла__ в БД - это не лучший подход, хотя и он имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: Если надо хранить аватарки пользователей, то я храню в конфиге путь относительно public папки: 'uploads/avatars', в этой папке для каждого пользователя своя папка название которой соответствует id, в этой папке хранятся картинки разных размеров. Если надо изменить путь uploads/avatars то не надо менять везде в бд, только в конфиге и перенести файлы в другую папку.

Comment: Вот советую использовать уже готовую библиотеку.
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary